Do minimal sufficient statistics always exist?
In Mathematical Statistics: Basic Ideas And Selected Topics - Vol 1, a sufficient statistic, $T(X)$, is said to be minimally sufficient if for any other sufficient statistic, $S(X)$, there exists a function $f_{ST}$ such that $T(X) = f_{ST}(S(X))$.
I'm wondering if minimal statistics always exist. For instance, could $S(X)$ and $T(X)$ be sufficient statistics for some distribution but there exist no functions $f_{ST}$ or $f_{TS}$ such that

$T(X) = f_{ST}(S(X))$ or
$S(X) = f_{TS}(T(X))$.


Yes (for all practical purposes) and no (in general). Practically (including all situations in  Bickel & Docksum's book), as long as a Radon–Nikodym derivative exists, Lehmann-Scheffé (1950)'s procedure will find a minimal sufficient statistic. Non-existence situations only come from very pathological cases under measure theoretic considerations, which I have to leave for others to comment/answer.
